# Wrong output of a dataframe print

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

The below code should display the following: (if today is 28.03.2020 and x is equal to 27)

```
No of days: 27
    Name DateOFBirth
0    Dan  2020-03-26
1  Brian  2020-03-01
```

Instead I get:

```
No of days: 27
    Name DateOFBirth
0    Dan         Dan
1  Brian       Brian
2  Marie         NaN
```

And the **code**

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime,timedelta

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Dan','Brian','Marie'],'DateOFBirth': ['26/03/2020','1/03/2020','12/02/2018']})
df['DateOFBirth'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateOFBirth'],format='%d/%m/%Y',errors='ignore')

x = input ("No of days: ")

today = pd.to_datetime(datetime.now())
result = today - timedelta(days=int(x)+1)


output = (df['DateOFBirth'] > result) & (df['DateOFBirth'] <= today) 
values = df.loc[output]
df['DateOFBirth'] = values

print(df)
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Third to last line should be: ```values = df.loc[output, "DateOFBirth"]```

Comment: May I ask how can I display only the names for which the DateOfBirth is in between result and today range?

Answer (score 0):

You could directly do

```
output = df[(df['DateOFBirth'] > result) & (df['DateOFBirth'] <= today)]
print(output)
```

that will assign the 'output' variable, the rows of your initial DataFrame for which the condition is true.

Comment: ```df.loc[...]``` is the recommended way. Also, however unclear from the OP's question, you can limit number of columns to extract: ```df.loc[<condition>, <columns_to_show>]```

Comment: Why is it recommended ?

Comment: Here you can find some official documentation on generally speaking - indexing in ```pandas```: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html but TL;DR - it's just faster ;)